# Is it possible to use Python backend and a Android/Native application as Front end

Tags: java, python, mobile, native, backend

I am handling my second year project which includes some machine learning backend along with a Mobile application front end.In simple terms i am creating
a androing/react native application which would take an input from the user and prosses in a backend development which includes python for some machine learning.

My question is, is it possible  to connect these 2 together. I have gone through some stuff altho i am not very clear on how to create a connection on this.

Also some opinions on either i should go with android or react native or any other language to go on python or not would be very  useful. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

For example, you can use Python as backend (server), with some exposed HTTP "interface", then make an Android application that communicates with these Python backend with HTTP request / response.

Or, if you are making a serverless application, you can make this Python backend as a `.so` library or using SL4A then call them in your Android application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can develop a python web service (REST OR SOAP) and use this for the backend for your application.

also, if you develop a service application (server-client) you must develop a service with python (or any languages) in your server after that connect your mobile application (reactjs, android studio, swift, ...) to this server.